# Obtaining marginal pdf from joint pdf

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

I am having trouble finding the marginal distribution of $Y$ in the example below:

*Let the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ be $f(x,y) = 1$, for $0<x<1$ and $x<y<x+1$.*

I tried something like $$\int_0^1 1 \, dx $$ but I think I got the integration bounds wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hint: try to draw the integration domain.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I can see that the joint pdf is defined over the area bounded by the lines $x=0$, x=1, y=x and y=x+1. My understanding is that in order to get the marginal of Y, I need to integrate out the joint over the domain of X, which is (0,1), but that does not seem to work.

Comment: This is because the pdf is nonzero not for $0 \le x \le 1$ but the boundaries of $x$ depend on $y$. Try to rotate the figure in $90^\circ$ to obtain $f_1(y) < x < f_2(y)$ and these are the correct boundaries (you should find $f_1$ and $f_2$ and the drawing will help you in that).

Comment: I tried to obtain $f_1(y)<x<f_2(y)$ as you suggest by rearranging $x<y<x+1$ as follows: $0<y-x<1$ $=>$ $-y<-x<1-y$ $=>$ $y>x>y-1$. This would give me $f_Y(y) = \int_{y-1}^y 1 dx = 1$ which is not the right marginal for $Y$. What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a really cumbersome way (or perhaps not a correct way of doing it).

I hope you noted the region is a parallelogram and the probability is uniformly distributed on this parallelogram. Then if you were to find the CDF, you can essentially finding the area.

What I found was $F_Y(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}$ if $0\leq y\leq 1$ whereas $F_Y(y)=1-\frac{(2-y)^2}{2}$ for $2\geq y \geq 1$. Differentiate if you need to get pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain why we proceed by splitting the domain of y into two parts ? Also, any explanations on how you come up with the cdfs would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I split it up because if you think about a parallelogram, you cannot integrate $x$ so easily here in the sense that the 'lower half' is integrating from $x=0$ to $y=x$ whereas the 'upper half' is integrating from $y=x+1$ to $x=1$ (Draw a picture would help). To answer your second question, this is just calculating the area for certain $y$ (Again, a picture would be very helpful)